# Импортировать библиотеку C на проект Java

Tags: c, java, библиотеки

Здравствуйте!
Вопрос достаточно странный. Есть очень хорошая библиотека dll с исходниками, написанная на чистом С. Вопрос : можно ли её импортировать в проект на Java ?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/49660/

Answer (score 2):

Смотря, что Вы называете импортировать.
Использовать  конечно можно, jni или jna Вам в помощь

- [JNI: взаимодействие Java с другими языками](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/jni.html)
- [JAVA native access examples](http://jnaexamples.blogspot.ru/2012/03/java-native-access-is-easy-way-to.html)

Но, честно, лично я не любитель, натива, объясню почему:

1. трудно отследить баги. использовал для связи с OPC, это OLE, есть ряд проблем, которые решаются не однозначно. В общем не прозрачная технология, имхо.
2. теряется кроплатформенность, да и вообще

Т.е. мысль основная в том, лично как подхожу я, если есть варианты использовать jni или java библиотеку, то предпочтение, я всегда отдам библиотеке на java.
Кончено когда речь идет о чисто платформо-зависимой технологии (например как OLE), тогда вариантов не много и то есть.

Comment: А если есть исходники на С, то что можно придумать, кроме dll, чтобы в Java проэкте использовать?

Comment: @stream2006, очевидно же - переписать исходники на java!

Comment: Ну да вроде нужно писать на Java, но прежде чем писать, проверьте, нет ли уже готовой библиотеки, жава комунити оно такое, на выдумки щедро ;-)...что хоть за либа?

Comment: Библиотека с функциями нечеткой логики и нейронных сетей

Comment: ну вообще не редкость, для java. есть свои реализации...
Посмотрите вот это, может пригодится:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85487/Benchmarking-and-Comparing-Encog-Neuroph-and-JOONE

Answer (score 0):

использовать COM ты можешь